# Make a dictionary of a csv file without imports

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

So I have a csv file of arbitrary amount of columns and rows (fully rectangular so no missing cells) of which I want to turn into a dictionary.

```
key1   key2   key3
1      2      3
4      5      6
7      8      9
```

I want to have a dictionary that will follow this pattern

```
{key1:[1,4,7], key2:[2,5,8], key3:[3,6,9]}
```

What I'm doing right now is reading each line. If I'm reading the first line each element becomes a key in the dictionary and maps to an empty list. Then I continue reading each line but here's where I run into the problem. I don't know how I assign the elements of each line to it's correct key (as dictionaries are random), that's assuming I know how to make generate a list of values that I can properly assign in the first place (for example, how can i make 1 go to key1, 2 go to key2 and 3 go to key3).

I want to do this all without imports. Let me know what you guys think.

Comment: [It's September once again...](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: It's a small part of an assignment, I've been pondering about it for over an hour now :/ It's the randomness of the dictionary that's messing me up. I did say what I was doing and where I am stuck, even a pointer would be great to get me back on track :/

Comment: Why don't you post the (presumably non-working) code that you wrote in over an hour then? We can then try to correct your error(s). You won't get any answers this way because Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service.

Comment: -sets off plagiarism checker- I did outline my thinking though and pretty much what the code was doing though. I'm stuck on assigning the list of elements for example [1,4,7] to key1 because of the randomness of dictionaries. I can't just say dictionary[0] = [1,4,7]. I'm not even asking for an answer, just something that will even hint towards how I should go about this will be good enough for me.

Comment: -facepalm- thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> s = '''key1   key2   key3
1      2      3
4      5      6
7      8      9
'''.splitlines()

>>> fields = s[0].split()
>>> rows = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in s[1:]]
>>> print(dict(zip(fields, zip(*rows))))
{'key1': (1, 4, 7), 'key2': (2, 5, 8), 'key3': (3, 6, 9)}
```

- `s[0]` is the first row of headings.
- The `.split()` breaks the words into the field names
- `s[1:]` gets the lines after the header row
- `line.split()` splits the row into field values
- `int(x)` converts the string entry *"1"* into the number *1*
- `zip(*rows)` transposes the list of rows
- `zip(fields, transposed_rows)` makes a list of key/value pairs
- `dict(list_of_pairs)` makes the dictionary

See references at:

- [int() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)
- [zip() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [dict() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict)
- [str.split() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [Tutorial coverage of string slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: I found a different way of doing but it out of curiosity what does zip do in general?

Comment: Thank you for the solid response,